# Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have problem with pipeline test on branch and master although it used to pass on the master before.

Today i update Android Studio, this can this can cause errors?

I run on branch:

```
./gradlew assemble
```

i get error:

```
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/ddlugosz/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d749d7039f211123753228b7812f7d3e/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/ddlugosz/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9e9187bd2896114f8594e23aebf1247b/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/ddlugosz/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/96174d1705ef219692d873bf56dce082/transformed/jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.3.20.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/ddlugosz/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4940e8dbd05acaea5533a602400cc173/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/ddlugosz/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ed956f66efced3ce23396a82f4e6b7ee/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
e: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext (in unnamed module @0x44f86d99) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x44f86d99
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.<init>(KaptContext.kt:29)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptContextForStubGeneration.<init>(KaptContextForStubGeneration.kt:40)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.contextForStubGeneration(Kapt3Extension.kt:285)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:169)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:100)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$invokeExtensionsOnAnalysisComplete(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:111)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:121)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:85)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:514)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:505)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:112)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:505)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:189)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:155)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I was looking for solution but not found

My kotlin version: `212-1.6.10-release-923-AS5457.46`

My android studio version: `Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683 May 18, 2022`

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/'
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
    }
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 80
        versionName "2.1.11"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0-beta02'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'

    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version"

    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.3'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:2.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.0.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Room components
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.2'

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-java8:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.5.1'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android"
}
```

project/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        ext.
                ktor_version = '1.1.2'

        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
            }

            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
            maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
            classpath "junit:junit:4.13.2"

            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.12'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.0'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a JRE issue. Which JDK are you using? Did this change? Also, do you have the problem only when running in the IDE or also when running Gradle via the command line?

Comment: @Joffrey I don't change JDK i use version 11.0.12. i run Gradle only via command line

Answer (score 1):

It resolve my problem:

I use Kotlin 1.6.10

but in project/gradle `classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10'` was set on 1.5.10, i change this for 1.6.10

and add new dependecies

```
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.32"
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32"
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10"
```